# style error messages - symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4

I need to style the error messages in the newSuccess.php template. 
I wrote this in configure():

```
$this->setValidators(array(

    'id' => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices'=>array($this->getObject()->get('id')), 'empty_value' => $this->getObject()->get('id'), 'required' => false)),

    'nome' => new sfValidatorString(array(), array('required' => 'Nome Obrigatório.')),

    'email' => new sfValidatorEmail(array(), array('invalid' => 'Email inválido.', 'required' => 'Email Obrigatório')),

    'contacto' => new sfValidatorString(array(), array('invalid' => 'Contacto inválido.', 'required' => 'Contacto Obrigatório')),

    'servico_id' => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('FeasyServico'))),

    'dia'        => new sfValidatorDate(array(), array('invalid' => 'Data Inválida.', 'required' => 'Data Obrigatória.')),

    'hora'       => new sfValidatorTime(array(), array('invalid' => 'Hora Inválida', 'required' => 'Hora Obrigatória.')),
));
```

so the field would be required and write the following code in newSuccess.php:

```
<?php if ($form['nome']->hasError()) { ?>

<span class="erro">
    <br>Campo Nome Inv&Aacute;lido
</span>

<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that the page is showing to messages: on styled(from newSuccess.php) and one unstyled(from configure()).

I need one of this things: or delete the message from configure() and only show the message that the previous code shows, or style the created error message from configure().
hope i explained my self well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your newSuccess.php :

```
<span class="erro">
 <?php echo $form['nome']->renderError(); ?>
</span>
 <?php echo $form['nome']->render() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... i just needed to put `display: none;` in the css class `error_list`. thank you